# Can Sublime plugin handle keys pressing, and key up/down?

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext

Can Sublime Text plugins handle event of

- key press (handle any key combination pressed, e.g. Ctrl+Alt+F1)
- key up/down (handle pressing of keys, and then releasing of keys)

If yes, how can my plugin handle these?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes** -- using [key bindings](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/key_bindings.html), which can be assigned in `yourplugin/Default (platform).sublime-keymap`.

You can also assign/customize global [User Bindings](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/key_bindings.html#user_bindings) (*e.g. keyboard or mouse shortcuts*)  by creating (*or modifying the existing*) `Default.sublime-keymap` file in your **`Packages/User/`** directory.

Comment: I don't see any mention of handling independant keyup and keydown events. Just support for high level keypress events.